# Apply a bunch of functions to columns of a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, apply

There is a way to apply a function `f` to every column of a matrix:

```
M <- matrix(seq(1,16), 4, 4)
apply(M, 2, mean)
#[1]  2.5  6.5 10.5 14.5
```

But if I want to build a descriptive statistics about matrix I should use more indeces. For example, `max, min, mean` etc.

But R doesn't allow to do something like this:

```
apply(M, 2, c(mean, max))
```

to get this output:

```
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#mean   2.5  6.5 10.5 14.5
#max      4    8   12   16
```

Would you tell me how to manage with this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
apply(M, 2, function(x) c(mean(x), max(x)))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]  2.5  6.5 10.5 14.5
# [2,]  4.0  8.0 12.0 16.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
f <- c("max", "min", "mean")
sapply(f, function(x) apply(M, 2, x))
     max min mean
[1,]   4   1  2.5
[2,]   8   5  6.5
[3,]  12   9 10.5
[4,]  16  13 14.5
```